# http sync request works, but same request async does not

Tags: ios, ios8.1

I know I am missing something VERY simple here.
I am trying to do a simple async http request. If I type the URL into a browser, I get the response I expect.

```
NSURL *convURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.186.212.144/API/index.php?action=%@&key=iOSAPIKey",action]];
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:convURL];
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"received data %@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

This returned the same JSON string that I see in my browser.

So now I try....

```
NSURL *convURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.186.212.144/API/index.php?action=%@&key=iOSAPIKey",action]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:convURL];
(void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I have the foundation library in my App. I import Foundation/Foundation.h in my viewcontroller.h file. I have NSURLConnectionDelegate in my .h file. I have didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, didFailWithError and connectionDidFinishLoading delegate methods set to log that they have been hit and to initialize, append or log the incoming data as appropriate.

However I get nothing. Any advice?

Comment: may u have to store the `NSURLConnection` object and call the `start` method from that instance....

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  I even created my own test project and see a response from the URL you posted.  What does your `connectionDidFinishLoading` look like?

Comment: - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Finished");}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is to send an asynchronous connection - which provides a callback. The callback, unlike returning data from a synchronous connection, will have the data for you. The reason it won't return data is because it spawns another thread under the hood to handle it for you, away from the thread your code is running in now (this is what makes it asynchronous, whichever thread spawned it keeps running onward, not waiting for the network call to return). Once the call returns, it executes the code in the callback.

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) { 
//Your code here 
}
```

Comment: I implemented this with a simple log of the returned data and got nothing in return. Again, a sync request to the same URL works prior and post this block, but I still get nothing within the async request.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer as it is working. I really am not 100% certain what this was, however a restart of both the phone and the laptop has now miraculously cured the problem, in conjunction with this solution. I note that the "normal" async method I describe in my example above still does not work, even after copying Ron's code verbatim. Totally confused.....

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine where the exact problem is, without seeing all of your code.  My guess is that maybe there is no instance variable to hold the received data or the variable is not initialized.  Here's what works for me:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *data;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *convURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.186.212.144/API/index.php?action=%@&key=iOSAPIKey",@"A"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:convURL];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        _data = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"The Connection is NULL");
    }   
}

#pragma mark - Connection methods

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_data setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Displaying the error message to the log.
    NSLog(@"Error description: %@",error.description);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Asynchronous done. Received Bytes: %lu", (unsigned long)[_data length]);
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [_data mutableBytes] length:[_data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"\n\nResponse: \n%@ \n", dataString);
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your example above into my app and I still failed to get a response. I was initialising my response data object in didReceiveResponse originally, but move it into viewDidLoad and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually start the connection.

```
NSURLConnection *connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Here is some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/start)

Comment: From the documentation..... "Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for the startImmediately parameter." I am not using the startImmediately=NO method.     I also have tried using the startImmediately method with NO, and then started the connection, and I still do not get any response. Thanks for the advice.